# On the topic of boundaries of discs in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no holomorphic function $f$ in the unit disc $\mathbb D$ that extends continuously to $\partial \mathbb D$ such that $f(z) = \frac1z$ for $z \in \partial \mathbb D$

I reckon I need to use the idea that $\frac1z$ has a singularity in the punctured unit disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, almost: If $f \colon \mathbb{D} → ℂ$ is holomorphic and continuously extendible to $∂\mathbb{D}$, then so is $g\colon \mathbb{D} → ℂ,\, z ↦ zf(z) - 1$. But if $f(z) = 1/z$ for $z ∈ ∂\mathbb{D}$, then the extension of $g$ would vanish on $∂\mathbb{D}$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler argument: $\int_{\partial D} \frac{dz}z = 2\pi i$, but Cauchy's integral theorem shows that $\int_{\partial D} f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every holomorphic function that extends continuously to $\bar D$.

Comment: I thought that one needs $f$ to extend holomorphically to some open set containing $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ to use that.

Comment: @k.stm if that version of Cauchy's theorem is not in your textbook, for the disc it's not hard to check that $f(rz)$ converges well enough to $f$ as $r\nearrow1$ to conclude that it's enough to assume that $f$ extends continuously to $\bar D$.